Is "Blink Twice" the first movie released in theaters with a trigger warning at the start?
Blink Twice (2024) opens with a trigger warning, which I've never seen in a theatrical release before. Here's what it says:


Trigger Warning
Blink Twice is a psychological thriller about the abuse of power. While this is a fictionalized movie, it contains mature themes and depictions of violence - including sexual violence.
This may be upsetting or triggering for some viewers.
AMAZON MGM STUDIOS

This caught my attention because I've never encountered a trigger warning in a movie before. I'm familiar with content warnings or "viewer discretion" advisories, but this is the first time I've seen the specific phrase "trigger warning" at the start of a film.
I'm curious whether Blink Twice is the first of its kind or if there have been earlier instances of movies using trigger warnings.
To clarify, I'm looking for an example that specifically uses the word "trigger" or "triggering" in its on-screen content warning, not just any content warning or "viewer discretion" advisory. The movie should have had a proper theatrical release, so TV movies, direct-to-video releases, or streaming-only films don't count. I'm also not looking for trigger warnings that might have been used outside of the actual film (e.g., in trailers or marketing materials).
Is Blink Twice the first movie released in theaters with a trigger warning at the start? If not, which movie was the first to do so?

@Paulie_D pointed out in the comments that the phrase "Trigger Warning" only really started gaining recognition around the year 2000, according to Google Books Ngram data. This suggests that if there were earlier examples, they'd likely be from the 2000s onward.

Fear Flasher and The Horror Horn

"Trigger Warning" is a phrase only really gaining recognition since 2000 - https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Trigger+Warning&year_start=1800&year_end=2022&corpus=en&smoothing=3#

@Paulie_D That's a helpful context, thanks. It narrows our search window considerably.

This article implies Blink Twice is the first film to explicitly and of their own volition include a trigger warning, and that "[some theatres] are [..] posting the notice as a title card on the screen before the trailers", which might complicate things.

While I understand the question, I kind of wonder whether restricting it to a specific modern phrase really provides anything useful. Is the warning really substantively different from "Rated R for mature themes, sexual violence, and abuse," which is the sort of warning that has been used for decades in the USA? That is a trigger warning, even if it uses different terminology. (Yes, theoretically the former term has a specific psychological nuance surrounding PTSD, but the meaning of the phrase as used here has drifted and really is just another iteration of a content warning/rating).

@Obie2.0 There's definitely overlap between content warnings and trigger warnings, but I'm particularly interested in when movies started using the newer terminology. "Trigger warning" has its own distinct history, and that's what I'm particularly interested in.
